# Manipulating ext4 partitions on C#

Tags: c#, file, ext4

Is there a library that can manipulate ext4 partitions with all the features that it provides for C#?

The other questions that asks about that everyone says that you should mount the partition with a program like [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) and operate it with the default IO File library. The problem is that with this method I still have the Full path name limitation of 255 characters, because the Windows IO library isn't expecting to write partitions that allows more than that.

Comment: Maybe should I change the question to "How to write files with full name greater than 255 characters on Windows"?

Answer (score 1):

The ext2fs library which is shipped as part of e2fsprogs has Windows support, but it's probably extremely bitrotted at this point.   Alas, lib/ext2fs/ntfs_io.c hasn't been updated in a long time, and lib/ext2fs/getsize.c only understands how to get 32-bit device sizes from Windows (at the time when the Windows code was last actively maintained, we didn't have ext4's 64-bit block number support yet).   And of course, there is almost certainly some Linuxisms that haven't been properly #ifdef'ed out.

That being said, e2fsprogs is supported on MacOS X and FreeBSD, in addition to having some very old Windows NT support code, so it is designed to be portable, and it is most certainly not Linux/glibc specific.   For that matter, it will even build on Android systems with the bionic libc!  :-)

If you want to try your hand at trying to modernizing e2fsprogs and/or just libext2fs for modern Windows systems, please feel free to give it a try and send me patches; I'm happy to review and integrate them.   Please use Linux kernel submission guidelines (not github pull requests, since they can't be reviewed effectively).   The git tree can be found here: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git